# This T-SQL script exceeds the maximum allowed size. Adjust this setting in the SQL Server Tools page by selecting Options from the Tools menu

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, sql-server-data-tools

I have a .sql scripts which is pretty huge. I added this script to a sql server project under visual studio 2013. When I try to build it I got this error message

> This T-SQL script exceeds the maximum allowed size. Adjust this setting in the SQL Server Tools page by selecting Options from the Tools menu

According to [this msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bb964729.aspx) article there is a property called `Maximum script size` it can be accessed in visual studio tools:

Tools->Options->Text Editor->SQL Server Tools->IntelliSense->Maximum script size

I changed it from 1MB to unlimited but nothing had changed

Comment: That particular setting only disables intellisense above the specified size. I think there must be a different setting you need to change.

Comment: Having the same issue here. I increased values in both `Tools / Options / SQL Server Tools / General` and `Tools / Options / Text Editor / SQL Server Tools / IntelliSense / Maximum script size`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 5):

Change the setting under SQL Server Tools -> General

[image]

Comment: I had the same issue where a specific script file was errored. It has a size of 55 MB. I changed the value from default (20) to 250 MB. No success. The description in the dialog explains that the WHOLE schema must not exceed the value we can set there, right? But VS is complaining about a single file... So I wonder where to adjust this? Any idea?

Comment: The only that worked for me was to exclude the file from the Build setting the "Build Action" to "None" in the file properties. It is not the fix of the problem, but, as it was in my case, the file was not intended to be built.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers/comments I'd like to point out that ReSharper also played a role in this game.

I configured VS like so:

```
Tools / Options / SQL Server Tools / General / Database model size: 20 megabytes -> 200 megabytes
Tools / Options / Text Editor / SQL Server Tools / IntelliSense / Maximum script size: Unlimited
```

Still getting the error (which is not a **build** error btw., but an IntelliSense error, MSBuild works fine).

A colleague applied the same configuration and it worked for him. The reason was that he did not have ReSharper installed.
After disabling ReSharper (2018.3.4 Build 183.0.20190304.43214) it worked for me as well.

We realized that there was a new version of ReSharper available (2019.1.1) and this one seems to have fixed the issue as well.

Just for reference: There is a [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/574780/sql71007-this-t-sql-script-exceeds-the-maximum-all.html) entry available with nearly the same content.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, changed both settings, and have never had ReSharper loaded.  This is a fresh install of vs 2019, with only microsoft extensions loaded. I had placed the very large sql script under the project/dbo/folder location.  When I moved it to under the solution as a solution item the database project compiled with no concerns.

Answer (score 0):

**As of Visual Studio 2022 this issue still exists.**

To get past the problem:

1. Modify the settings described above by [@Martin Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/73226/martin-smith) and [@timmkrause](https://stackoverflow.com/users/824483/timmkrause).
2. Open the properties of the "offending" file (shown in Visual
   Studio's Error List output).
3. Change the Build Action from "Build" to "None" and rebuild.
4. Once successful, you can now restore the Build
   Action back to "Build".